# Why does my page refresh when I click the filter button in my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to build a filter with a razor page to filter optionally off of user input on a search box and a drop-down. In other words, they can filter off either, both or not at all.

I followed this tutorial here, and was able to have everything work correctly, but when I tried to do the same thing but with my own data and my own application for more practice, it did not work. I am not aware of anything different.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
     //Controller Method
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string travels, string 
searchString)
    {
        IQueryable<string> travelQuery = from c in _context.CardInfo
                                         orderby c.Travels
                                         select c.Travels;

        var cards = from c in _context.CardInfo
                    select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            cards = cards.Where(c => c.CardName.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(travels))
        {
            cards = cards.Where(x => x.Travels == travels);
        }

        var cardInfoVM = new CardInfoViewModel
        {
            Travels = new SelectList(await 
                        travelQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
            CardInfos = await cards.ToListAsync()
        };

        return View(cardInfoVM);
    }


    //Model
    public class CardInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CardId { get; set; }
        public string CardName { get; set; }
        public int Elixir { get; set; }
        public string CardType { get; set; }
        public string Travels { get; set; }
        public string Targets { get; set; }
        public string AttackAir { get; set; }
        public string Spawner { get; set; }
        public int RangeLevel { get; set; }
    }

    //ViewModel
    public class CardInfoViewModel
    {
        public List<CardInfo> CardInfos { get; set; }
        public SelectList Travels { get; set; }
        public string CardTravel { get; set; }
        public string SearchString { get; set; }
    }



//cshtml view


  @model ClashMVC.Models.CardInfoViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
 }

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
  <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form asp-controller="CardInfo" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>
   <select asp-for="CardTravel" asp-items="Model.Travels">
           <option value="">All</option>
    </select>

    Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
</form>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CardInfos[0].CardId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CardInfos[0].CardName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CardInfos[0].Elixir)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CardInfos[0].CardType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CardInfos[0].Travels)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CardInfos[0].Targets)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CardInfos[0].AttackAir)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CardInfos[0].Spawner)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CardInfos[0].RangeLevel)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.CardInfos)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CardId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CardName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Elixir)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CardType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Travels)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Targets)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AttackAir)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Spawner)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RangeLevel)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route- 
id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

There is no error message. I see the expected query string parameters in the browser, but when I try to apply a filter based off of the dropdown (CardTravel) the page reloads and the filter is not applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Controller Index method parameter

```
string travels
```

needs to match the View's

```
select asp-for="CardTravel"
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I somehow made the drop-down ugly, but your suggestion worked!

Answer (score 1):

For sure the `<input type="submit" value="Filter" />` will cause the page reload because of you have an input/button with type="submit" inside the form. If you don't want to refresh the page after clicked, please use JS/Jquery (or anything else) to make an async call to Controller